# Do I need bank statement for dependent spouse?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

For an Italian Schengen visa application, do I need three original recent bank statements for the dependent spouses, as well?

Comment: What is your nationality and what is your spouses' nationality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the supporting documents for your spouse’s visa application should be as full and complete as yours.  Both her cover letter and yours should state clearly that you’ll be travelling together, and that you’re covering the expenses for both of you. You should also mention it to the consular officer accepting your documents, so that your applications are processed simultaneously.